# Authentication Token for mobile app, is there a offline brute force vulnerability?

Tags: security, authentication, cryptography, access-token

from what my understanding is, with token based authentication, a client sends his username/pass and receives a token. and then uses this for auth.

( Background information on my goals so you can better understand what i am trying to do, is simply to use a token to authenticate users on a android app, to the sql database )

Mobileapp - Sends username/pass ->  Server / Api

Mobileapp <- sends token - Server / Api

Mobileapp - Uses token to retreive data from server - > Server / api

Mobile app <- sends info - Server / api

in the case of a mobile app, does this token not reside on a users phone? 
i think i am misunderstanding a key concept here. but does this not mean that no matter how well we encrypt it, it can be broken in time, and thus our secret key will be revealed? and once the secret key is revealed can the user not generate authentic auth for other users?

Possible solution 1: i was thinking s upon the user signing up, they are given a secret key user for that user, which could be stored with their information on the server instead of a universal secret key, so even if it is broken it will not work for other users, is this how people go about preventing this type of thing?

solution 2 or combined with one, would be to make each users key expire after 24 hours, and make encryption on the key that would take at least 24 hours to break, to provide a decent level of security? however the problem with this is the users password would need to be stored somewhere, which opens the problem of it being brute forced anyway.

please excuse my ignorance, ANY and all help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

A token is derived from *some* information and a private key. Getting the private key from that token is as likely as getting the private key from the corresponding public key (very unlikely if the key material is correctly created). And in order to forge a token, you need the private key. To sum it up, if you derive the token correctly, an attacker will only be able to use the token for as long as it is valid, not forge another, and not get your private key.

Comment: i appreciate this. are you able to go into this a little further, from what i've read a token is simply created using some info as you said, lets say id + email or something simillar, and is then encrypted resulting in a string to be used as a token. 

if i store this on the users phone. they have unlimited time to break the tokens key, im not sure i understand the public vs private aspect of what you are referring to. 
i apologise i've just come home from work and am very tired, i hope i am being coherent :)

Answer (score 0):

The attacker cannot obtain the Private Key from cracking the token stored in the device. It is not about time, it's just not possible.
The token can be stored in the device if you're planning to provide a longer session active period. but I'd recommend to expire it after 24 hours at least. Otherwise, you don't need to store the token in the device if you're planning to maintain the session active for 15 minutes, lets say. You could instead save the token in memory and expire it when:

- User signs out
- After 15 minutes of user inactivity
- When user closes the application

Keep in mind that in order to harden security, it is recommended Not to use concurrent sessions (multiple active tokens per user). It's recommended to expire all remaining active sessions (tokens) every time the user issues one. And yes, this means that user needs to enter credentials every time. It's not recommended to store the user's password on the device. However, you can store the user's username with the user's consent of course.